# How do we apply execution_timeout to any task in airflow. It should also give out an email notification if a task fails

Tags: airflow, timedelta

I want this task to fail and give out an error notification.

```py
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_10s',  # Cause the task to miss the SLA
    bash_command='sleep 10s',
    execution_timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds = 5),
    #sla=datetime.timedelta(microseconds=10),  # SLA for the task
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`email_on_failure`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/717a7588bc8170363fea5cb75f17efcf68689619/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L709) parameter.

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_10s',  # Cause the task to miss the SLA
    bash_command='sleep 10s',
    execution_timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds = 5),
    email=['airflow@example.com'],
    email_on_failure=True,
    dag=dag)
```

Note that sla miss doesn't necessarily mean failure of task.